# Two functions with same name: One static How to declare in header file

Tags: c, header-files

I have two .c files names: Main.c and Test2.c. I defined a function:  `void TestExtern2()` in Main.c. I defined another function with same name but it is static: `static void TestExtern2()` in Test2.c. I put the declaration: `void TestExtern2();` in header file.

I compile:

```
$ gcc Main.c Test2.c and get this error:
error: static declaration of 'TestExtern2' follows non-static declaration
```

Is there a way around this. I mean I want to provide the function declaration in the header file but also need to keep the name of both functions same.

Comment: in C, there cannot be duplicate function signatures within the same scope.

Comment: Could you explain why you end up "needing" this? Sounds very strange. There are probably better options.

Comment: And what behavior do you expect? How should a call to the external `TestExtern2` and to the static one be distinguished?

Comment: If you **need** to access the same function in multiple source files, `define` the function in one of the files, then `declare` the function as `extern` in the other.

Comment: "Is there a way around this?" Yes - rename one of the functions.

Comment: 1) Make both `static` 2) test.c does not include "the header file".  BTW: Why should it? what is in `main.c` that `test.c` needs to see?

Answer (score 2):

The same function cannot be declared both static and non-static in the same translation unit.  If your `Test2.c` genuinely needs a static function named `TestExtern2` then it must not include a header file with a conflicting declaration of that function.

That doesn't prevent you declaring the (non-static) function in a header file; it just means the source file containing the static version must not include the header, or else that the header must allow it to use conditional compilation to suppress the non-static version of the declaration where necessary.  For example:

TestExtern.h

```
#ifndef TESTEXTERN_H
#define TESTEXTERN_H
#ifndef SUPPRESS_TESTEXTERN2
int TestExtern2(int);
#endif
#endif
```

Test2.c

```
#define SUPPRESS_TESTEXTERN2
#include "TestExtern.h"

static double TestExtern2(const char *s) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Do note, however, that "TestExtern2" is an exceedingly strange name for a `static` function, because static linkage and external linkage are mutually exclusive.  Understand, too, that the two distinct functions having the same name does not in itself confer any advantage on you whatsoever.  Despite sharing a name, they are different functions, and in any given translation unit, every appearance of their name will refer to the same one of them.  It can easily lead to confusion, however, because the name will refer to different functions in different translation units.

It would be much better to just give your different functions different names, at least where one has external linkage.